# How to generate static pages in yii

Tags: yii, static

In one project we need to generate static pages with and not store content on database. We are using Yii framework. Does somebody know the approach that can be implemented in this task? How does one generate static pages in Yii framework? There will thousands of static pages that should be created by users, so how I can edit them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things.

1. Make HTML/PHP files in another folder that is not under the "protected" directory.  Then you can access them: http://mysite.com/files/pagename.html
2. If you want the same template as the main page, but just different content, put them in the protected/views/site/pages folder.  you can then access them by index.php?r=site/page&view=pagename
3. You can manually create a route for each page in the controller that loads a view, but this sounds out of the question since users will be creating the content.
4. And probably the best way.  Upload the webpage content to the database, store it.  Then you can use Yii/Gii Crud tools to get some basic pages laid out to edit those new pages.  You would just have to create a way to render those pages as you would like, stripping out bad tags and such.

Comment: the problem is that the content should'nt be stored in the database